# How to set FONT based on the language in SSRS Report?

Tags: fonts, formatting, ssrs-2012

i have column values in English and Japanese in my database. on my SSRS report i need to implement the font type based on the data.
For an example, my report has a column called Description. If the value under description is in English then the font should be "Arial" if in Japanese then "AndaleWT".

Description

Apple                      --> This should be in Arial Font.

林檎                       --> This should be in AndaleWT.

Please help me on how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the data set? I would add a language field, then set the font based on the value of that field.

If not, you could try something like this (old link, but appears to still be valid): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171960(v=office.11).aspx

And here's a slightly newer link: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/03/15/language-detection/

You would have to create this function in the code behind the report, then call it in the Font property of the text box. If you don't know how to do that, let me know and I can help you with it.